# Arriving JSON entity is being incorrectly mapped in Spring Controller's method signature

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am passing json object. All but Timestamp properties is being set correctly. Timestamp properties of Entity is set to 1970 year ...smth. How to fix it?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addProduct", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public Product addProduct(Model model, @RequestBody Product product, BindingResult result){
        cService = (ProductService) context.getBean("productService");
        cService.addProduct(product);
       return product;
    }
```

**json input:**

```
{"name": "ag","dateTimeStart": 1411568760,"dateTimeEnd": 1412100000}
```

**Product entity:**

```
@Table(name = "product")
@Entity
public class Product implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "product")
    private int product;

@Column(name = "name")
    @Basic
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

@Column(name = "date_time_start")
    @Basic
    private Timestamp dateTimeStart;
@Column(name = "date_time_end")
    @Basic
    private Timestamp dateTimeEnd;
}
```

**Added record to database:**

```
name ag
dateTimeStart 1970-01-17 10:06:08
dateTimeEnd 1970-01-17 10:15:00
```

**UPDATE**
I am using MySQL. I pass unix epoch timestamp and expect it to be correctly stored in database.

Comment: You'd have had this done hours ago if you didn't insist on using a fancy-dancy mapping API but instead just wrote the code to map it yourself.

Comment: Why Spring fails to complete such a trivial task? What is the fastest fix for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a annotation for your JSON mapper, that instructs him to map the date via timestamp.

Comment: Please provide example